# How to use abstract names of unix domain sockets with fastcgi in nginx?

Tags: nginx, perl, fastcgi, chroot, socket

I tried some perl examples of unix domain sockets using abstract names:
Created a socket starting with a null character:

```
my $socket_path = "\0wibble";
```

using netstat -nlp I can see the socket:

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     309510   3448/perl            @wibble
```

In examples all is working, but...
I want to use fastCGI in nginx with unix domain sockets using abstract names:

So in nginx.conf:

```
Using       fastcgi_pass  "/tmp/wibble"; #is Ok
But using       fastcgi_pass  "unix:Any_name"; #is not Ok!!
```

I tried `\0wibble \zwibble \x{0}wibble` and it didnt work!

At fastcgi-wrapper.pl I tried:

```
Using        $socket = FCGI::OpenSocket( "/tmp/wibble", 10 ); #is Ok
But using       fastcgi_pass  "unix:Any_name"; #is not Ok!!
```

I tried `\0wibble \zwibble \x{0}wibble` and it didnt work!

**BTW**: I want to use chroot on nginx and chroot in perl, so I cannot use a filesystem socket, as it will be a path out of jail and a security flaw...

Comment: In Linux, if the name starts with null it is an Abstract Name, as described in unix(7).

Comment: I am trying to execute a Perl CGI script. Both Perl and nginx are chrooted. So I dont want to hard link an unix domain socket using filesystem, as this can be exploited. I want to use an Abstract Name, but I cant make it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx doesn't support abstract sockets (as of today). However [an unofficial patch exists](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,200086,200086) which provides this support. Once applied, you can refer to an abstract socket as `@wibble`. If you use this patch, be sure to read the entire nginx forum thread regarding it, as it refers to various changes made to the patch.

Comment: I am sad I will need to recompile it, but I am glad it exists. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi!
I think we also have another alternative...
Instead of moving from FGCI to uWSGI, I could also try to chroot twice (nested chroot)...
This way the pathname is out of second jail, but it is inside the first...
But I didnt tested if this can be exploited easily... I am sure the second jail can be exited, but i neet to research escaping from the first jail...

Comment: Hi again! Ive discovered that using socat I can relay between pathname or abstract namespace named sockets! This way I can relay from the jail to an abstract socket! thank you @michael-hampton!